# JQuery Validate plugin: how to control the max size of the selected value of a dropdown?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following select tag in HTML

```
<select name="field">
    <option value="123">option 1</option>
    <option value="14567">option 2</option>
    <option value="ab">option 3</option>
</select>
```

When a form is submitted, I hope to use the validate plugin to validate the max size of selected value is no bigger than 5 chars (example values: 123, 14567, ab) and show a message if the size is too big. I cannot figure this out. Adding the maxlength attribute to the select tag does not work.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: **Firstly, show the rest of the relevant code.**  Secondly, when validating a `select`, the `required` rule is the only one that makes sense.  This is probably because it's illogical to present your users with options they're not allowed to select. Finally, [the `max` rule works](http://jsfiddle.net/zg7h09ra/).  It's not *exactly* what you want, but you can write your own rule using the `.addMethod()` method.

Comment: Sparky, I would like to add limited validation on the user interface. The html in a visitor's browser can be easily manipulated. I could limit what exact values are allowed from a dropdown list, which I do not plan to do. I also need to validation non the server side too. Sorry about not presenting my code, which was a standard use of addMethod I found from the plugin's sample code. Your answer really expanded my view. Cheers.

Comment: If you're implementing this validation rule because the interface can be manipulated, then *any* JavaScript approach will be subject to the same kinds of manipulations.  The only way to protect from browser/JavaScript manipulation of form data, is with server-side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to write and implement a custom method as shown below...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod('selectlength', function(value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || value.length < param[0];
    }, "option must be less than {0} characters");

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                selectlength: [5]
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/80mcutdg/**

---

Although IMO, it does not make any sense to present your users with options they're not allowed to select in the first place.

Comment: Sparky, thanks so much for your input. I know how to do aaddMethod, but I simply did not know something like function(value, element, param) based on my research. Thanks, again!!!